# Grails- Exception when rendering Joda dates as JSON

Tags: grails, jodatime, grails-2.0

I'm trying to render command validation errors as json but I'm getting an exception. The command object is using joda time DateTime objects instead of java.util Date objects. The code to do the json rendering looks like:

```
def results = eventSaleDataCommand.errors.fieldErrors.toList()
def errors = []
for (error in results) {
    errors.add([
        'type'          : 'invalid_entry',
        'field'         : error.field,
        'rejected_value': error.rejectedValue,
        'message'       : error.defaultMessage
    ])
}
render errors as JSON
```

The exception I'm getting is:
`Class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.converters.marshaller.json.GenericJavaBeanMarshaller can not access a member of class org.joda.time.tz.DateTimeZoneBuilder$PrecalculatedZone with modifiers "public".`

Anyone know how to get around this?

Comment: What version of the JodaTime plugin are you using? Or are you not using the plugin at all and just using JodaTime as a library/jar?

Comment: I've got a dependency to 'joda-time:joda-time:2.0' in my BuildConfig dependency block.

Comment: Okay, by default Grails doesn't know how to render JodaTime classes as XML or JSON. However, there is a plugin that adds this support into Grails. I suggest you look at using it instead: http://grails.org/plugin/joda-time

Comment: Unfortunately the app I'm working on is a Grails 2.2.3 app and the plugin requires version 2.3 and higher.

Comment: Then your best bet is to implement your own converters. You can use the plugin as an example: https://github.com/gpc/grails-joda-time/blob/master/src/groovy/grails/plugin/jodatime/converters/JodaConverters.groovy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implementing a Joda converter did the trick. Thanks.